# Powershell Adding fields/object to the output of a get-hotfix command

Tags: powershell

I need to show more information in this script, like SO version

```
 foreach($vc in Import-Csv $lanzadera){
       #Write-Host "$($vc.serverNameCLI)"
       $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user,$pass
       Invoke-Command -ComputerName $vc.serverNameCLI -Credential $cred -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable Problem  {
            ##this variable $ssoo is the one i like to add
            $ssoo = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).caption

            $Patches = 'KB4457984', 'KB4463104', 'KB4467700',#Server 2008 sep,oct,nov
                       'KB4343899', 'KB4457145', 'KB4462915', 'KB4467106', #Server 2008 R2 ago,sep,oct,nov
                       'KB4343896', 'KB4457140', 'KB4462931', 'KB4467678', #Server 2012 ago,sep,oct,nov
                       'KB4343888', 'KB4457143', 'KB4462941', 'KB4467703', #Server 2012 R2 ago,sep,oct,nov
                       'KB4343887', 'KB4457131', 'KB4462917', 'KB4467691' #Server 2016 ago,sep,oct,nov
            Get-HotFix -Id $Patches
        } 

        foreach ($p in $Problem) {
            if ($p.origininfo.pscomputername) {
                Write-Warning -Message "Patch not found on $($p.origininfo.pscomputername)" 
            }
            elseif ($p.targetobject) {
                Write-Warning -Message "Unable to connect to $($p.targetobject)"
            }
        }   
}
```

The output in the console looks like:

```
Source        Description      HotFixID      InstalledBy          InstalledOn               PSComputerName                       
------        -----------      --------      -----------          -----------               --------------                       
server00001   Security Update  KB4343899     server00001\sysieci  10/02/2018 0:00:00        server00001                          
server00002   Security Update  KB4457145     server00002\sysieci  10/02/2018 0:00:00        server00002
```

So, how can I add more column/objects, using the Get-Hotfix command?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of other columns or objects would you like to add? I would imagine you can pull the additional data and store it n a variable and pipe the output together in the resulting table or do a join and export to a csv file

Comment: the usual methods are [1] to build a new object that has the items you want OR [2] use `Add-Member` to add new props to the original object. the 1st is neater & easier to read/maintain. the 2nd is somewhat more direct.

Comment: Hi, just the version OS  : Microsoft 2012....

Comment: Check out [calculated properties](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/01/19/using-powershell-calculated-properties.aspx)